# Clicking on Action Bar Menu Items in Robotium

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, robotium

I'm trying to run some automated tests in Robotium. I have the following code in my application which sets up an options menu :

```
  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu menu) {
    com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.layout.logoutmenu, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
```

I try to click on the menu in Robotium using the code :

```
solo.sendKey(Solo.MENU);
solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.share)); //share is the id of the menu item
```

However my tests fail due with the error :

```
View is null and therefore cannot be clicked.
```

I have also tried using the code below which also failed :

```
solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.logoutmenu));
solo.clickOnMenuItem("Share My Artists");
```

Comment: are you running your tests this on Android 2.3?

Answer (score 18):

if you are running Robotium tests on Android 4.0+, consider using `solo.clickOnActionBarItem()`.

Comment: Just for people wondering about the correct parameter, it is "int id" so don't put {0, 1, ...} but R.id.your_id. ; )

Comment: I want to click on overflow menu on the action bar and click on setings item. solo.clickOnActionBarItem(0x1); worked before but now its not working, I think something has changed i dont know what, appcompat action bar. I am testing using apk I dnt have access o R.id.x

Answer (score 1):

Just do that :

```
solo.sendKey(Solo.MENU);
solo.clickInList(5);
```

5 is the position just change it to the position of your Menu item
the First is 1 , the Second is 2 etc.

Answer (score 0):

I could get it working on all the SDKs, using this:

```
View ab = _solo.getCurrentActivity().findViewById(R.id.action_bar);
ArrayList<View> views = _solo.getViews(ab);
for (int i = 0; i <views.size(); i++) {
    if (views.get(i).getClass().getName().contains("ActionMenuPresenter")) {
        _solo.clickOnView(views.get(i));
        _solo.waitForText(SOME_TEXT);
    }
}
```